# Kotlin: Declaring subclasses of an Activity static

Tags: android, android-studio, static, kotlin, subclass

After converting Java code to Kotlin for an Activity consisting of a subclass Fragment, the layouts won't render appropriately anymore (logcat errors towards the bottom of this post). I figured because declaring subclasses of an Activity must be declared **publicly static**, and this is what I have after converting to Kotlin:

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            finish()

            return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    // Apparently the following class must be declared static.
    class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle, rootKey: String) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_main)
        }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        }

        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
        }
    }
}
```

... I tried changing the fragment's modifier to "object" and even stored the whole class within a companion object, and yet the app crashed with the same exceptions.

Here's my fragment XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.davenotdavid.dndheadlines.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</fragment>
```

Exceptions thrown:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment                                                                          
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment                                                                          
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState
```

... All of that said, how do I properly declare subclasses of an Activity **publicly static**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking in Java parlance, a class [nested](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html) in another is `static` by default in Kotlin (and all classes are `public` by default). This shouldn't be a problem.

You are getting an exception because of nullability though: you should make your `savedInstanceState` parameter in `onCreatePreferences` a nullable `Bundle?`, because this function may be called by the framework with a `null` value, and it will crash your app every time that it is if the type here is non-nullable.

So what you want to end up with is this:

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_main)
}
```

Comment: Gah! Should've known. Apparently I had to make the String param rootKey nullable as well... Thanks bud!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a null safety issue from your stack trace.  Since you're allowing nulls on each of the other Bundle related methods, have you tried adding:

```
  override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_main)
    }
```